# Use string as argument of a function (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, string, arguments

I have a general problem with JavaScript. I am trying to construct long argument used in function in my project via separate method. In the end I am able to produce a String with necessary arguments, however I cannot insert it into the method as parametres. When I do, I get different errors from the API I am using. Problem is, that there are several parametres in the method and when I insert the method generating said arguments, the method treats those arguments only as a long String. I've tried using eval() and String() methods, however without success.

I know that those generated arguments are correct, because when I use console and do everything step by step, I can generate those arguments and then manually copy them in the method, which works.

Could anyone tell my how to force the browser to treat inserted String as a "code already written in method"?

Thanks and sorry for not including the code, I cannot show it to anyone yet.

Edit:
The code looks similar to this:

```
function buildArguments(args) {
    var title='Something';
    var interval=1;
    var type='Something';

    var build = '{title: {text: "' + title + '"},' +
        'axis: { interval: ' + interval + '}, ' +
        'dataType: { type: "' + type '"}};'
    return build;}

function graph(args) {
    var graph = new MyGraphAPI.Create(buildArguments(args));
    graph.chart();}
```

and it should create something like this:

```
var graph = new MyGraphAPI.Create(
    {
        title: {text: "Something"},
        axis: {interval: 1},
        dataType: {type: "Something"};
    }
);
```

It's possible there are some mistakes, I've written the code in haste only as an example. However you should get the idea.

Edit2: I should also add that those arguments in build function are used in creating the final string of arguments in final method (even though I didn't include this in the example).

Comment: Can you give us an example of what the code kind of looks like?

Comment: Maybe show us a use-case?

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") **must** include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.* — If you "cannot show it to anyone" then construct a test case which shows the principles along with expected input and output.

Comment: I expect the best solution to the problem will involve the `apply` method.

Comment: Why are you writing `build` by mashing strings together? The only variables involved are property values. What is wrong with just writing `var build = {
 title: {
  text: title
 },
    axis: { 
     interval: interval 
    }
 dataType: { 
  type: type
 }
};` and passing that?

Comment: Because there are many more arguments, some containing fields etc. and I generate them according to situation.

Comment: @MichaelIris — The question remains. Why are you generating them as a string (hard to do, hard to maintain) instead of object literals (easy)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the string to object. Something like:

```
  callfunc(eval("{a:1,b:2}"));//equals callfunc({a:1,b:2})
```

If you want to pass multiple arguments, and they are into an array, you can do:

```
callfunc(...["arg1","arg2"]); //equals callfunc("arg1","arg2");
```

Both together:

```
 callfunc(...eval("['arg1',{someobjval:1,someabjvaltwo:2}]"));
```

However this is bad style. Why do you need a string? Can't you just build an object/Array?